# Firebase: Observe email verification status in real time

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

How would I be able to check in real time if the user verified his email?

My flow is like this:

1. User registers
2. Email is sent
3. User sees "Please verify your email" notification

Now I would like to:

4. setInterval -> check if email is verified
5. If verified show the "Email verified" notification

For this I would need a method that fetches the user data from firebase.
Usually you just use the onAuthStateChanged callback to get userdata but I need to explicitly fetch current data.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a way!

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()
```

will fetch current user data. So all I have to do is this:

```
              this.checkForVerifiedInterval = setInterval(() => {
                firebase.auth()
                  .currentUser
                  .reload()
                  .then(ok => {
                    if (firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified) {
                      this.props.history.push("/verification-email-verified")
                      window.Materialize.toast("Email verified.", 3000)
                      clearInterval(this.checkForVerifiedInterval)
                    }
                  })
              }, 1000)
```